# EntityFieldQuery can do automatic trimming on conditional field?

Tags: drupal, entity

Is there a easy way to trim the field value automatically?

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->fieldCondition('field_news_types', 'value', 'spotlight', '=')
  // See the comment about != NULL above.
  ->fieldCondition('field_photo', 'fid', 'NULL', '!=')
  ->fieldCondition('field_faculty_tag', 'tid', $value)
  ->fieldCondition('field_news_publishdate', 'value', $year . '%', 'like')
  ->fieldOrderBy('field_photo', 'fid', 'DESC')
  ->range(0, 10)
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.

$result = $query->execute();
```

Take `field_news_types` for example, any text field could do, what if I want to trim it before the query. Is there some macro parameter to use?  So `"spotlight "` will also match?

Answer (score 0):

If you really are looking to just trim white space, you can simply pass the tested value through PHP's [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
...
->fieldCondition('field_news_types', 'value', trim($news_type), '=')
...
```

If you need to do a partial string match you can switch to a `like` condition (which you already have an example of):

```
->fieldCondition('field_news_publishdate', 'value', $year . '%', 'like')
```

Comment: I think you missed the point. I want to trim the value in the database field so I can still find it.

Comment: To do that through the Drupal API I believe you need to use the partial string match (LIKE) listed above.